# limits of integration for polar curves

Tags: calculus

I have a question about which order to put limits of integration for polar curves. Say I wanted to find the region enclosed by the curve $r= 2\cos\theta$ from $5\pi/3$ to $\pi/6$ (not the other way around). How would I do this? thanks!

Comment: Since area is always a nonnegative quantity, and since switching the limits of integration just changes the sign, you can actually choose any orientation you want, and then take the absolute value of your answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer! what i'm confused about, however, is that the limits seem to be sweeping different areas depending on the order. take, for example, this graph (linked). If I wanted the area between 5pi/3 to pi/6, wouldn't that be a different area than pi/6 to 5pi/3? and together those areas would add up to the area of the entire circle? http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427elmcrnbqadp

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Yes, as joriki mentions in his answer, it would be best then to use the limit of integration $\frac{13\pi}{6}$ instead of $\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you mean the area that lies at angles in $[5\pi/3,2\pi]$ or in $[0,\pi/6]$. To get this area, either perform those two integrations separately, or note that adding $2\pi$ makes no difference for your purposes, so you can integrate over $[5\pi/3,13\pi/6]$ in one go.