# Question about limits of integration for polar curves

Tags: calculus

Why do I get different results when I integrate 
$$\int 2\sin(θ) \, \mathrm{d}\theta$$ on $\left[\dfrac{5\pi}{6},\pi\right]$  versus $\left[\dfrac{5\pi}{6},\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right]$?
Isn't the area contained between these limits the same? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think that they are equal?

Comment: This question can only be understood in the context of [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382889) and the comment under my answer to it. The integral over $2\sin\theta$ doesn't appear to be what was intended, as is clear from the comment under Ethan's answer.

Comment: because no additional area is bounded by r=2sin(theta) and the lines theta= 5pi/6 and pi than is bounded by r=2sin(theta) and the lines theta=5pi/6 and 3pi/2. I apologize, the integral in the original question above is incorrect for finding the area. I simply want to find the area bounded by the curve r=2sin(theta) and these two different sets of limits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering based on the assumption that you're not actually interested in the integral that you wrote in this question, but in the area of the curve defined in your comment to my answer to your previous question. (This underlines the fact that it's usually helpful to include links to earlier related questions.)

That curve is only defined for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$, since $2\sin\theta$ is negative for $\theta\in(\pi,2\pi)$, and the radius $r$ cannot be negative. If you don't intend $r$ to be the radius in polar coordinates, and are simply interested in the curve $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ regardless of the sign of $r$, then note that in this context $\theta$ is not the polar angle, either, and the part of the curve in which $\theta\in(\pi,2\pi)$ actually lies at polar angles in $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: thank you very much @joriki! I am currently working on an assignment that involves finding the different areas formed by the graphs of r=a, r=2asin(theta), and r=2acos(theta). thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}-\cos(\theta)=\sin(\theta)$$

$$-2\cos(b)+2\cos(a)=2\int_{a}^b\sin(\theta) d\theta$$

$$2-\sqrt{3}=-2\cos(\pi)+2\cos(\frac{5}{6}\pi)=2\int_{\frac{5}{6}\pi}^\pi\sin(\theta) d\theta$$

$$-\sqrt{3}=-2\cos(\frac{3}{2}\pi)+2\cos(\frac{5}{6}\pi)=2\int_{\frac{5}{6}\pi}^{\frac{3}{2}\pi}\sin(\theta) d\theta$$
$$2-\sqrt{3}\ne -\sqrt{3}$$

So they are not the same

Comment: thank you for your response. What I mean is, I am trying to find the area of r=2sin(theta)from 5pi/6 to pi. But shouldn't this answer be the same as that from 5pi/6 to 3pi/2, simply because the curve does not lie between 5pi/6 and pi? the integrals would be using the 1/2(f(theta))^2 formula for area, of course.

Answer (score 0):

http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP151222ccbb62909g8d410000620h0e1d2e06078e?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=52&w=200.&h=120.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips
http://www4c.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP80032108h4heb6i59ch700000ce4a343h15b44e5?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=8&w=200.&h=116.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips

These are the graphs respectively. The blue region has positive are and the pink one has negative area hence the total area in second case is negative (as one can see the pink region is large).

Comment: oh, I see, thank you! how can this be explained using the polar graph? http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e6d2r3qh2c4

Comment: have a look at this and try inputting other value for $\theta$ [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%3D2sin%28theta%29%2C+theta%3D+5pi%5C6+to+3pi%2F2)

Comment: @Girish Pictures are dead.

Comment: Where did it go?